# Weird jump with Quicksand jquery

Tags: jquery, quicksand

I'm using quicksand jquery script. I want a div to be shown at all time (the one with the grey background in the demo). It is set to float on the right of div#wrapper.

If you click "Braillon affair" then "All" in the filter menu, you'll see that there is a little jump at the end of the animation.

http://braillon.net/alain2/

Can you see any workaround?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some data-id are not unique. Always check them :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and tried everything and as it turned out I was running a slightly older version of the plugin -- so be sure to check that you're up to date!